# Triple Boot Windows 7/ Windows 8 RTM/ Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, dual-boot

What is the best way to triple boot Windows 7 Home Premium, Windows 8 Professional RTM, and  the latest version of Ubuntu? I already have Windows 7 and Windows 8 installed. I am currently downloading Ubuntu. I don't want to lose either of my OS's. Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Take a look into GRUB. It is the Linux bootloader of choice for most linux distributions. It will boot Windows 8 just like Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

1. Make sure it will not go beyond the 4 primary partitions, otherwise, your PC will not boot up.
2. You can make extra partitions with the Gparted tool, but it will not aloww more than 4 primary partitions, (more extended parititions are allowed )
3. After making the sufficient space for Windows 8 then
4. Install Windows 8
5. Now you notice that only Windows 7 and 8 are listed in Windows' boot loader
6. Now you have two options:

   1. add Ubuntu in Windows' boot loader by using [easyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)
   2. Reinstall grub 2 by with a live CD. to see video  [click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lod8sRb_6I)

      After this if your windows in not listed in grub 2 then type `sudo update-grub2`

      Even if Windows is not listed retry after mounting your Windows drive

      Have a look at [this video for updating grub2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJDcyAncmRY)

Answer (score 0):

My machine also runs Windows 7, Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10. Ubuntu is one I installed the last, and GRUB2 automatically list all my other OS, so I don't have any boot problems.

But, if you want to use Windows 8 GUI bootloader, you can download EasyBCD and set it up from there. Windows 8 GUI bootloader boots Windows 8 faster (since it actually just a hybrid-boot), while selecting Windows 7 or Ubuntu (from the Windows 8 GUI bootloader) makes your computer restart and boot to your selected OS.